# DateTimeFormatter in Mule DataMapper

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component

I am using dataformat conversion inside DataMapper script in Mule.

```
dateTimeFormatter = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");

output.Date_of_Rate_Float__c = (isnull(input.Date_of_Rate_Float) ? null : dateTimeFormatter.format(input.Date_of_Rate_Float));
```

When I am trying to save the mapping. I am getting below error

```
Root Exception stack trace:
org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConversionException: DateConverter does not support default String to 'Date' conversion.
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.DateTimeConverter.toDate(DateTimeConverter.java:468)
```

But when I remove the dateTimeFormatter, I am not getting any error. I need to use dateconversion, is there any other way to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You were keeping **Date** datatype as **string** and trying to format the date. Change the Date datetype as **DATETIME** and the do the conversion.